# Incompatibilidad entre FirebaseAuth de las dependencias admin y auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-auth

Estoy desarrollando una app con java para android en la que necesito hacer el login de los usuarios. En la misma tengo un usuario con rol de administrador que se encarga de gestionar los usuarios desde la misma app.

Para ello me hacen falta las dependencias

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
```

Cuando he dado a sync en el gradle app, me he encontrado con que la clase FirebaseAuth es la misma, se importan igual

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
```

y ya no reconoce los métodos propios de la clase auth, pero si los de admin. Por ende ya no reconoce el metodo del login de los usuarios.

¿Alguien ha tenido que lidiar con algo similar y puede aconsejarme?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola no veo la biblioteca firebase-admin dentro de las bibliotecas actuales de Firebase para Android, me parece que el firebase-admin es para aplicaciones del lado del servidor, lo que te recomendaría es utilizar solo el firebase-auth.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419#available-libraries

También te recomendaría es utilizar firebase-ui-auth que es una biblioteca basada en el SDK de Firebase Authentication que implementa buenas prácticas y controla los flujos de autenticación para una implementación limpia y sencilla.

https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/auth/readme/

Comment: Gracias por la info!! Pero, ¿sería posible que un perfil de admin borre usuarios de auth de alguna manera?